# Getter properties not found for `DbSet`s on my `Context`

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, entity-framework-6, data-binding

I have a `DbContext` used by a WPF client of a WCF service I 'host' in a Windows Service. Now, I don't know how this is related to what, in the WPF client, when I use the designer to place a `SchedulerLogView` on my `SchedulerView`, it shows as a red cross, and somewhere I can extract the error message

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1<Strategico.Eals.Services.Models.EalsLogEvent> Strategico.Eals.Data.Context.EalsDbContext.get_LogEvents()'.
```

This tells me the `get` accessor for `LogEvents` is missing. How can part of a Framework library be missing?

`LogEvents` is defined inside `public class`public classEalsDbContext: DbContext`:

```
public DbSet<EalsLogEvent> LogEvents { get; set; }
```

It is used inside `public class LogViewModel`:

```
public ObservableCollection<EalsLogEvent> LogEvents { get; set; }
...
using (var db = new EalsDbContext())
{
    var dbEvents = db.LogEvents.Where(e => e.PkId > max).ToList();
}
...
LogEvents.AddRange(dbEvents);
```

Which is bound to a `DataGrid` inside `SchedulerLogView`:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding LogEvents}"
```

Comment: Is the EalsDbContext your own implementation or 3rd party? Does the EalsDbContext has a property `LogEvents` of type `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Strategico.Eals.Services.Models.EalsLogEvent>` when you view it in the ObjectBrowser of VS or in the code file

Comment: @Jehof, yes, it does. If I write sample code in a console app I can query  that `LogEvents`.

Comment: Arent't you by chance trying to expose the db context or db set as a result of a wcf method?

Comment: Can you provide a sample code where `LogEvents` is defined and how you are trying to use it?

Comment: @bpiec I have added an example, for what it's worth. Sorry, also changed tag from `wcf-binding` to `wpf-binding`.

Comment: @Claies The `DbSet` is not publically exposed from the view model at all. It is used inside the `using` block in my example. I know enough to know I which one I am using.

Comment: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/930

Comment: Any reason why you are not using `db.LogEvents.Local`. That itself is an ObservableCollection. You don't need to create one I suppose.

Comment: @RaviMPatel, I'm trying to maintain separation of concerns, and my access to the DbContext object anywhere in the UI shouldn't be happening, ideally. My example, of such access in the viewmodel, is the result of a late addition to basically still a prototype version. I haven't really created anything; all I do is instantiate an `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add reference to `EntityFramework.dll`. I had the same issue. Turns out, you need the `EntityFramework.dll` reference (and not `System.Data.Entity`)

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Comment: this may indeed be the case, but right now I can't reproduce the problem until I get around a more important one. I have had issues with what describe before.